# Me salta el error de "Something went wrong" en mi móvil al scanear el expocli

Tags: android, terminal, expo

Expocli error
[image]
Bueno este el error que me aparece al escanear mi app desde mi celular en la terminal de visual studio code

[image: expo]

Answer (score 0):

Este es un error de Expo, pero que es similar a de cualquier biblioteca que usamos en nuestras apps:

> This project uses SDK 42.0.0, but this version of Expo Go only
> supports the following SDKs: 49.0.0, 48.0.0,47.0.0. To load the
> project, it must be updated to a supported SDK version or an older
> version of Expo Go must be used

**Este error indica que tu versión de SDK debe ser 49, 48 o 47, pero tu versión actual, como se indica en las dependencias, es 42.0.0**

Por lo tanto la solucion es que debes actualizar la versión de expo SDK usando el comando "expo upgrade".

Revisa [actualizar Expo SDK](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)